# predetermine the size of a function at object file level

Tags: memory, memory-management, size, stack, stack-size

how to predetermine the size, a function will consume in the RAM during the execution. This has to found at the **object file level**? 
ie - to be more clear, If I have a object file, I should able to say that this file consumes this much BSS, DS, CS and stack and heap. In this I can able to sort out BSS, DS and CS using size and also nm commands, but cant able to deternmine how much stack or heap will be consumed.

can any 1 help me out this..

thanks in advance
kihdrak